# Не могу обрезать переменную ошибка?

Tags: java

Нужно чтобы переменная value  приняла форматированное   значение  переменной  Toast_otv

Так ошибка??

```
 double value= format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%.7f", Toast_otv);
```

Comment: Какая ошибка? что за метод такой `format`?

Comment: сама переменная типа `double` не может быть форматированным, форматируется непосредственно вывод значения переменной куда-либо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@duna, переменная типа double не может быть отформатирована. Она занимает свои положенные 8 байт и имеет 16 разрядов в дробной части. Именно поэтому тип и называется "двойной". Потому что его разрядность в два раза больше, чем у типа "float" (8 разрядов после запятой).

```
double d = 13.0 / 7.0;
System.out.println(d); // В консоль выводится: 1.8571428571428572
float f = (float) d;
System.out.println(f); // В консоль выводится: 1.8571428
```

Однако, не всегда бывает удобно, когда в качестве результата отображается такое длинное представление числа. В этом случае можно отформатировать сам вывод. Число останется тем же, а на экране будет показан его отформатированный вид:

```
System.out.printf("%.2f", d); // В консоль выводится: 1,86
```

Если все-таки необходимо изменить само число до определенного знака после запятой, то можно его округлить. Метод round() округляет до ближайшего целого числа, поэтому, чтобы округлить число до 4-х разрядов после запятой, нужно сначала умножить его на 10 в 4-й степени (10000), затем округлить, а затем снова разделить на 10000. Вот так:

```
double r = Math.round(d * 10000) / 10000.0;
System.out.println(r);  // В консоль выводится: 1.8571
```

Делить нужно обязательно на `10000.0`, а не просто на `10000`. Это для того, чтобы результатом деления получил тип double, а не int.

Соответственно, для округления до 2-х разрядов после запятой:

```
double r = Math.round(d * 100) / 100.0;
System.out.println(r);  // В консоль выводится: 1.86
```